# react-native-elements: icons throw Invariant Violation error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-native-app, vector-icons

I'm new to react native and I face a problem I have no idea how to solve.
I created and started a new project as follows:

- create-react-native-app ProjectName
- cd ProjectName
- yarn add react-native-elements@beta
- npm start

The package.json looks like this:

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta3"
  }
}
```

Then I wanted to insert a button with an icon like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <Button
          raised
          icon={{ name: 'cached' }}
          title='BUTTON WITH ICON' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Unfortunately, I get this error message:

[error message on iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pByWu.jpg)

Does anyone have a hint how I can make the icons work? I already tried to add the vector-icons with 'yarn add react-native-vector-icons', although I do have a create-react-native project, but that did'nt work neither.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the error message in text form to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this way:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
...
<Button
  icon={
    <Icon
      name='arrow-right'
      size={15}
      color='white'
    />
  }
  title='BUTTON WITH ICON'
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. I was just taking the card example from react-native-elements as example and they did integrate the button differently. :)